# File download for jsp application

Tags: java, ajax, file, jsp, download

I am working on a jsp application and I have a download zip file feature

I have done

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {​​"/retrieve"}​​, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void logDownload(@RequestBody ResponseDto responseDto, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {​​
    
    Byte[] arraObj=downloadService.getdownloadFile();
response.setContentType("application/octate-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=user.zip", 
    response.getOutputStream().write(arraObj);
    }
```

I am making a ajax call for this controller

JSP Side code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/retrieve",
    headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(retrieveDto),
    success: function (res) {
        window.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result";

    },
    error: function (e) {
        // window.location="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result";
        console.log("There was an error with your request..." + JSON.stringify(e));
    }

});
```

I am unable to download the file
Can someone tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?  Can you confirm that your logDownload method is called each time you click in your jsp application?  Have you debugged your jsp application to see if it is properly receiving the response from the controller?  How does your jsp application create a folder when you get the response?  If you could post some of your jsp application (the onClick and processResponse areas), that could help.

Comment: @MarkBrown Yes for each click the controller is getting invoked, Let m update the jsp part

Comment: Thejas I don't see where you are saving the file in your jsp code.  Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: @MarkBrown for the second click the files gets downloaded to a folder